# Free product when 2 of a certain brand are purchased (no limit on discounted product)

Tags: magento-1.7, promotions, free-gift

Disclosure, i did search for an answer to before posting this question.  But i am new to this also.  So patience would be appreciated.

I would like to do a promotion with the following parameters in Magento:

**Customer must:**

- 1 x Free product when 2 x products from within a certain brand are purchased
- no limit on free product

  - So long as at least 2 products within the brand are purchased
  - customer can purchase in multiples of 2 from within the same brand and redeem the free product for each multiple of 2
  - I.e. if a customer purchased 6 products within the brand, they would receive 3 x free of the free product

Hope this makes sense.  It does to me but ive been looking at it too long

Comment: Hi. This is not natively possible. You would need to look for a 3rd party ext or custom code. I will of course punt my own work (http://www.proxiblue.com.au/premium-modules/magento-free-gift-promotions-extension.html) but there are others available. You need to get the one that works for you.

Comment: Ta mate.  will look at your work